# Recursively rename folders based on length

Tags: powershell

I have thousands of files in thousands of directories.  Some of these paths are out of control and longer than what Windows can handle, so when I try to access the files within PowerShell, I get an error.
How can I rename folders within these paths if they contain a certain length of characters? (for example, like 50+ characters for one folder)

**Edit:**

No, it is not Linux.

**Error:** 
This is when I do a recursive searce to find all files on the server.

> Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
>   The fully qualified file name must be less than 26 0 characters, and
>   the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Is this a linux fileserver? As you said, Windows's filesystem can't handle very long filepaths(max is 259 chars i think). If you try to move, rename or create a file that hits the limit, you will hit an error.

Comment: Please post the error you receive after addressing @Graimer's question.

Comment: Correction: is it windows fileserver? san? clusterd file system? :)  Also, if `Get-ChildItem` and Windows has a problem handling the filename, how are we supposed to rename it USING powershell. I'd suggest using another OS. Maybe someone got a better idea.

Comment: I haven't tried it but there is an experimental BCL contribution on CodePlex that handles long paths including methods to enumerate file system entries and move support:  http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with another person on the code, we were able to come up with something that works.  I actually had to make the search length smaller because some of these paths were really out of control.

```
takeown /f \\server\share\foo /r /d Y /a >c:\takeown.log

$folders= Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\share\foo" -recurse | where {$_.PsIsContainer}
$sortedfolders = $folders | sort-object -descending -property fullname
foreach ($f in $folders) {
if ($f.name.length -gt 10) { 

   rename-item $f.fullname (get-random).tostring()
   } 
}


$aolesfolders | gm

$sorted | ft fullname
$aolesfolders | select-object name, root, fullname, parent | export-csv     c:\testrename.txt
get-random | gm
(get-random).ToString().gettype()

foreach ($f in $folders) {
if ($f.name.length -gt 10) { 

   rename-item $f.fullname (get-random).tostring()
   } 
} 

{rename-item $f.name $f.parent+}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`subst`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx) to map the parent folder to a drive letter and continue from there.